# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I was watching youtube regarding webscraping and would like to give it a go. I tried mimicking exactly how the tutor teaches but I land into a problem right away.

```
(node:20976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.  
       at rewriteError (D:\Users\Win81\Desktop\Web-scraper-snkrssg\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:261:23)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
   at async ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (D:\Users\Win81\Desktop\Web-scraper-snkrssg\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:161:64)
   at async D:\Users\Win81\Desktop\Web-scraper-snkrssg\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:90:30    
   at async DOMWorld.$x (D:\Users\Win81\Desktop\Web-scraper-snkrssg\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:96:26)
   at async scrapeProduct (D:\Users\Win81\Desktop\Web-scraper-snkrssg\scraper.js:10:18)
(node:20976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20976) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is the sample of my codes:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.goto(url)

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="block-1565393554829"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div/img[2]');
    const src = await el.getProperty('src');
    const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();

    console.log({srcTxt});

}

scrapeProduct('https://shopnicekicks.com/pages/calendar');
```

I hope someone could teach me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It seems that the page reloaded or was redirected. Try running puppeteer with `headless: false` to watch what's going on.

Comment: Just change the line page.goto(url) to await page.goto(url)

Comment: I've tried the method Eduardo Conte mentioned and it works! Thank you so much for the help. And by running it headless I was able to also see what happening. Thanks to Vaviloff for the guidance too.